# Radio button add different columns in various numbers in datatable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
 example_table = $("#example2").DataTable({
                       "ordering": false,
                       "lengthMenu": [ 8, 16, 32],
                       "columns": [{
                                      class: 'alignCenter'
                                    }, {
                                      class: 'alignCenter'
                                    }],
                       });
```

datatable initialized.

```
for (var d = 0; d < 8; d++) {
                   example_table .row.add([

                        'GP ' + d.toString(),
                        '<input type="radio" id="' + d.toString() + '" name="q' + d.toString() + '"/> ',
                        '<input type="radio" name="q' + d.toString() + '" checked/>',
                        '<input type="radio" class="dop" name="q' + d.toString() + '"/>',
                        '<input id="' + (d).toString() + '" data-toggle="clear" name="check-1" type="checkbox" class="lcs_check" autocomplete="off" /> '

                    ]).draw(false);
```

There are tables added. 5 columns and 8 rows.
I need 2 columns only 4 radio buttons. How can I accomplish that?